# Use PHP to change a website logo from FTP

Tags: php, html, ftp

I have created a website and want the user to change the logo of the site through their admin area I have created. I have mastered the uploading of images to FTP through PHP, but now want them to be able to select that image they have uploaded and display it as the logo.

Is it possible to do this? The only way I can think of doing this is with an echo but that isn't very user friendly as they'd have to type it in rather than select from the directory.

Any suggestions?

**Edit:**

After a little bit of thinking is it possible to upload from local server to ftp, and save the path the a mysql database, enabling the use to then update the logo that way.

It does seem a very long winded way for a simple task though...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you just have to create a form on your admin panel with input type file.

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
```

After submit the form you have to save your image using move_uploaded_file to your specified location e.g. path images(this path should have permission to save files from website) and save this path on your database if file is saved. Then you just have to show image using url + your image name from database(please remember about the unique names of your images).
I think this could help http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

BTW. In my humble opinion there is nothing to do with ftp.